# Distinct values in data bound combobox

Tags: c#, data-binding, distinct-values

I have a table Inventory(ItemId,Name,Size,Price,otherinfo) where ItemId is primary key and Name,Size,Price are unique.
When I bind the combobox with Name all repeated names appear while i want each name to appear just once, same happens with Size.

**How to load unique values in combobox which is bound to a datasource?**

Comment: If you want it to bind to unique names, then you can't bind to the itemID. As I understand you could have data like ID=1, Name=A; ID=2, Name=A, which means that these records are already unique as their keys are different. And if you only bind to names, how do you know if a user selected Name A from ID 1 or ID 2? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, i want to bind to Name. I have two other comboboxes for Size and Price. So that if a user select basket, large, 20 it will return a unique ItemId.

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion for doing this? I want user to select Name, Size, and price and get unique itemId as result

Answer (score 9):

You can do this, (you may have to tweak it a bit to complie and work for you)

```
ddlName.DataSource = items.Select(item=>item.Name).Distinct().ToList();
ddlName.DataBind();

ddlSize.DataSource = items.Select(item=>item.Size).Distinct().ToList();
ddlSize.DataBind();

ddlPrice.DataSource = items.Select(item=>item.Price).Distinct().ToList();
ddlPrice.DataBind();
```

And then find the itemID based on the selection of all three dropdown lists.

This is C# and assumes that you have LINQ

Hope this helps.

Edit-- (if no LINQ)

```
IList<string> names = new List<string>();

foreach (Item item in Items)
    if (!names.Contains(item.Name))
        names.Add(name);

ddlName.DataSource = names;
ddlName.DataBind();

//Do similar for price and size.
```

Edit (use SQL commands)

```
select distinct Name from Item
select distinct Size from Item
select distinct Price from Item
```

Comment: What if i don't have LINQ? I am making it in .net 2.0.  What is 'items' in this code?

Comment: I have a dataset and tableadapters to get values or sql itself